# Resteasy client in an OSGi / Eclipse RCP environment

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, resteasy

I'm trying to build a client for a Resteasy service in Eclipse. I thought this would be simple - but a lot of the magic that Resteasy does (e.g. looking up annotations on POJOs, loading the Resteasy providers, etc.) seems to be broken by the OSGi class loader. I've spent quite a bit of time resolving the problems with dependencies and buddy policies, but I've come across a stumbling block. I'll describe it, but the best possible solution would be a pre-existing set of OSGi/Eclipse plugins for the resteasy client. Failing that..

```
could not find writer for content-tyope application/xml type: com.company.Pojo
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest.writeRequestBody(ClientRequest:473)
```

This is resteasy 1.2.1.GA.

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - managed to sort this in the end, although it's not the most elegant solution.

Steps to take:

1. Use Eclipse's create plug-in from JARs wizard
2. Import

   - jaxrs-api-1.2.1.GA.jar
   - resteasy-jaxrs-1.2.1.GA.jar
   - resteasy-jaxb-provider-1.2.1.GA.jar
   - jaxb-api-2.1.jar
   - jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar
   - slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
   - slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar
3. Export the following packages

   - javax.ws.rs
   - javax.xml.bind.annotation
   - org.jboss.resteasy.client (and all subpackages)
   - org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers
   - org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb
   - org.jboss.resteasy.spi
4. Add that plug-in as a dependency, and obtain a reference to the client in the usual way